# Shiny App Rerun source code

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny App that calls different R scripts using the `source()` function. How do I trigger the source files to be executed again if it detects a change in reactive input? I tried the code below, but it doesn't refresh.

```
 detectDateChange = reactive({    
    newDate <<- as.Date(input$date)        
    source('./script_to_rerun.R', local=TRUE)
})
```

I also tried `rm(list=ls())`, but it's not refreshing.

For the output, I'm using a plot variable in the source file. How do I get this variable to be updated once the source files are refreshed on date change?

```
output$plotArea = renderPlot({
    pltVariableFromSourceFile
})
```

Comment: If you add a print statement to your reactive function, does it print every time the date changes? Maybe `observe` would be a better option here?

Comment: By using `observe` I managed to trigger the source file to execute again. However, the plot output doesn't refresh in my code (see edit in question).

Comment: IIRC that's because there's nothing in `renderPlot` to cause it to trigger again. Try putting `input$Date` in there. You don't have to use it for anything, it just has to be in there to cause Shiny to re-render the plot.

Comment: Thanks! Thanks a brilliant hack.

Comment: Happy to help. I feel like 65% of the code I write in Shiny is just me trying to hack something, haha!